# Where to find the warning of `Warnings found during shrinking`?

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, proguard, android-proguard

After adding RxAndroid and Retrofit library to my gradle, and compile, I got the below error, shows in my Android Studio Message panel.

```
Error:Execution failed for task 
':app:transformClassesWithNewClassShrinkerForProductionDebug'.
> Warnings found during shrinking, please use -dontwarn or -ignorewarnings to suppress them.
```

In my Debug, I use

```
        minifyEnabled true
        useProguard false
```

I believe I could use `-dontwarn` or `ignorewarnings` to suprress and let the compilation continue. But I would like to know what warnings was that. Where could I find the warning?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Found it. Just need to open the `Gradle Console` (normally a tab at the right bottom) to look at the Gradle Log.

It is stated

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task 
':app:transformClassesWithNewClassShrinkerForProductionDebug'.
> Warnings found during shrinking, please use -dontwarn or -ignorewarnings to suppress them.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
```

Optionally, I could just need to run the `gradlew` on command line with the `--debug` option.

```
./gradlew :app:transformClassesWithNewClassShrinkerForInternalDebug --debug
```

Answer (score 3):

It is like the default shrinker has changed. Adding the configuration to turn on ProGuard started to work.

```
buildTypes {
    release {
        debuggable false
        minifyEnabled true
        useProguard true
        getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'),'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
    debug {
        debuggable true
        minifyEnabled true
        useProguard true
        getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'),'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
```