# debug app build failure after enabling proguard

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, minify, android-proguard, android-multidex

```
Error:Execution failed for task 
':app:transformClassesWithAndroidGradleClassShrinkerForDebug'. 
Warnings found during shrinking, please use -dontwarn or -ignorewarnings to suppress them.
```

How do i fix this?

PS- also I want to use `progaurd` in my application.

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    buildToolsVersion '26.0.2'

    dexOptions{
        javaMaxHeapSize="2g"
    }

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.projetinnovation.newadvocatediary"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 26
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        multiDexEnabled=true

    }
    buildTypes {
        debug {
            minifyEnabled true
            useProguard false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-andr    oid.txt'),
                    'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.    txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

repositories {
    maven {
        url "https://jitpack.io"
    }
    google()
}
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile project(path: ':agendacalendarview')
    compile 'pl.droidsonroids.gif:android-gif-drawable:1.2.2'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.+'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:26.+'
    compile 'com.loopj.android:android-async-http:1.4.9'
    compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
    compile 'com.mcxiaoke.volley:library:1.0.19'
    compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.+'
    compile 'com.github.clans:fab:1.6.4'
    compile 'com.github.dmytrodanylyk.android-process-button:library:1.0.4'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:10.0.1'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.github.ybq:Android-SpinKit:1.1.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:26.+'
    compile 'com.github.d-max:spots-dialog:0.7@aar'
    compile 'com.github.ganfra:material-spinner:2.0.0'

    compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.+'
}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Comment: try this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44389680/where-to-find-the-warning-of-warnings-found-during-shrinking

Comment: when you use minifyenabled and proguard there are chances that some classes from your library gets stipped away from the build. You have to identify which class is getting removed and then add proguard rules for keeping that class when creating build. Also avoid using + for your gradle libraries

Answer (score 0):

You need to add -dontwarn or -ignorewarnings to all third-party libraryes in proguard-rules.pro You can find description on docs/wiki pages of them